# forcing double tap in code

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uigesturerecognizer, gesture, uitapgesturerecognizer

Is there anyway to fire a double tap gesture in objective C code?

I want it so that when this line of code is executed, it would be as if a double tap gesture just happened on the screen, even though the user did no such thing.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

For this you have to synthesize your touch events.
I haven't tried it but **[here's](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/synthesizing-touch-event-on-iphone.html)** a tutorial that does something like that.
One more thing what ever you want to do on double tap, why don't you call that code where you wish to create double tap gesture.

Comment: Hi I can't call the code that i wish to create the double tap gesture because its a private method in another class that is part of another framework that I have no access to.